# React Only return props.children

Tags: reactjs

All:

I am pretty new to React, I wonder how can I build a logic only component without adding any element(only used to processing some data), something like:

```
class LogicCom extends Component {
    constructor(props){super(props);this.props = props;}
    render(){
        return (
            {this.props.children}
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `return ({this.props.children})` is invalid JavaScript. `{this.props.children}` is not a valid object literal. Maybe you where thinking about JSX, e.g. `<div>{....}</div>`. In here the `{...}` have different semantics, but in your code there is no JSX.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

**EDIT** In React v16+, you can return strings and arrays from components. So, it is perfectly valid for a component to simply return its children...

```
render() {
  return this.props.children
}
```

Read more about it in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html).

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

What you have will work IFF there is only one child (and you fix your syntax errors). However, children can be an array of many children and you cannot return an array in a `render` function. So, you must do one of two things...

1. Enforce that your component only accepts a single child with [React.Children](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrenonly)...

```js
class LogicCom extends Component {
    render(){
        // this will throw if there are many children
        return React.Children.only(this.props.children)
    }
}
```

2. Wrap the children in another component...

```js
class LogicCom extends Component {
    render(){
        return <div>{ this.props.children }</div>
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so basically there has to be some additional `<div>`, this is normally unavoidable?

Comment: Good call on `React.Children.only()`. That should work as long as there is only one child, like you said. If there are multiple children then they have to be wrapped.

Comment: @Kuan There has to be some additional `<div>` IF your component accepts multiple children. If it only ever accepts one child, use #1 above and you don't need the additional `<div>`

Comment: I guess you could conditionally do #1 or #2 depending on how many children there are in real time :P

Comment: Thanks, `return <div>{ this.props.children }</div>` was not immediately obvious to me, but does make sense for an array of child elements.

Comment: This is answer is outdated since React v16. `render` functions can now return fragments, i.e. an array of children.

Comment: This entire question is pretty obsolete now but I added an update for v16

Comment: There is also `return <>{ this.props.children }</>`. This won't produce any DOM element.

Answer (score 6):

React components **MUST** have a single root DOM element to render.

From [the official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#render):

> The render() method is required.
>
> When called, it should examine this.props and this.state and return a
>   single child element. This child element can be either a virtual
>   representation of a native DOM component (such as  or
>   React.DOM.div()) or another composite component that you've defined
>   yourself.
>
> You can also return null or false to indicate that you don't want
>   anything rendered. Behind the scenes, React renders a  tag
>   to work with our current diffing algorithm. When returning null or
>   false, ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this) will return null.

In your case it's easy enough -- just wrap your `this.props.children` in an outer element of some kind.

```
render(){
    return (
        <div>{this.props.children}</div>
    )
}
```

Comment: OK,thanks. But I wonder how react-router implemented, when I include route inside <Router /> the only element I get on the page seems only my component, there is no additional router element

Comment: @Kuan are you sure about that?

Comment: Sorry, I am not totally sure, I remember there is no addition element

Answer (score 5):

You can wrap your children with React.Fragment component

```
class LogicCom extends Component {
    constructor(props){super(props);this.props = props;}
    render(){
        return <>{children}</>
       // or return <React.Fragment>{children}</React.Fragment> it's the same
    }
}
```

Comment: best answer because it's the most minimal

Answer (score 4):

You *can* return children only without wrapping the children. Trick is to create a wrapper *component* then modify children into an array, which is required by React.

Wrapper.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class extends Component {
  render() {
    return React.Children.toArray(this.props.children);
  }
}
```

Now you can simply just wrap anything else in this wrapper component.

```js
<Wrapper>
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed semper odio nec semper suscipit.</p>
</Wrapper>
```

Now the elements inside the wrapper will render without having to wrap it in a DIV.

Answer (score 2):

As [JCD stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39133868/747303), render must return either a single root child or `null`. There are a couple other options:

If `LogicCom` doesn't need to pass data down the tree, it could be used as a leaf.

```
<Parent>
  <LogicCom />
  {/* other children */}
</Parent>
```

If you do need to pass data down (e.g. LogicCom manipulates its incoming props or generates new props), you can either require a single child as described in [@Charlie's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39133898/747303) (further documented with [propTypes](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#single-child)):

```
class LogicCom extends Component {
    render(){
        // this will throw if there are many children
        return React.Children.only(this.props.children)
    }
}

LogicCom.propTypes = {
    children: React.PropTypes.element
};
```

Or use the Higher-order Component construct to wrap another component:

```
const LogicCom = function (Wrapped) {
    return class extends Component {
      render () {
          // forward received props and override/add as needed
          <Wrapped {...this.props} />
      }
    }
};

// usage elsewhere: WrappedComponent will receive whatever props LogicCom
// receives + overrides/adds.
const WrappedComponent = LogicCom(AnotherComponent);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Functional component](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50274058/104380) can simply return the `children` prop, *as-is*

```js
const Wrapper = ({children}) => children

ReactDOM.render(<Wrapper>123</Wrapper>, document.body)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```