# What classifies as a React functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am following a tutorial on Udemy where the instructor is trying to explain HOC.

To explain HOC, he created a function having a functional component (at least this is what he said). This is the code:

```
const withClass = (WrappedComponent, className) => {
     return (props) => (
         <div className={className}>
             <WrappedComponent {...props} />        
     </div>

   )
 }
```

The React documentation displays this example:

```
function Welcome(props) {
  return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
}
```

And mentions:

> This function is a valid React component because it accepts a single “props” (which stands for properties) object argument with data and returns a React element. We call such components “functional” because they are literally JavaScript functions.

**[Question]**

In simpler words, is it safe to say that: **Any function which takes props as an argument can be classified as a functional component? If not, can someone explain in a nutshell about functional components in React?**

Comment: ...and returns valid React node or null.

Comment: Tomasz I think I got your point but to be sure, Can you explain in details in the answer section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any function which takes props as an argument can be classified as
>   a functional component?

No, props is just the function argument, like all other normal function arguments. So if we define any function that accepts an argument it will not necessarily be a React functional component, like this is not a React component:

```
const Testing = props => {
   const a = 10;
   return a * props.a;
}
```

The important part is **"If that component returns a React element"**, only then will it be a React functional component.

To make it more clear just define the below function in a separate file; it will **not** throw any error when you transpile:

```
const Test = props => props.key * 10;
```

But if you define this below component in a separate file without importing React, it will **throw error**, React is not defined, when you transpile:

```
const Test = props => <div>{props.key * 10}</div>;
```

Because **[JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html)** will get converted into `React.createElement(....)` and React will be required. The [**converted version**](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAKgU2jAvDADgJxOiqB8MAPACYCWAbvgN5Y4QB0A1ggJ4wBUMAjAAwC-RAPTkqAbiA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=) of the above component will be:

```
var Test = function Test(props) {
  return React.createElement(
    "div",
    null,
    props.key * 10
  );
};
```

I will suggest, use [Babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/) and define both the functions and check the output.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a function, which takes props as an argument can be classified as a functional stateless react-component.

This function should return a valid component answer; e.g., React node, array, number, string or null.

Such a function has no state and you can't set up component lifecycle methods with it.

Your JSX code is transformed into a React.createElement function, that receives either a "native" component, e.g., div, span or function.

To clarify my answer I'll include the simplest React.createElement realisation (Dan Abramov posted this code on JS Bin some time ago):

```js
// Necessary for JSX to work
window.React = {
  createElement(type, props, ...children) {
    return {
      type,
      props: {
        ...props,
        children: children || props.children
      }
    }
  }
};

// What kind of node are we dealing with?
function getNodeKind(node) {
  if (node === false || node == null) {
    // A hole: false, null, undefined
    return 'EMPTY';
  }
  if (typeof node === 'string' || typeof node === 'number') {
    // Text or number: 'Hello', 42
    return 'TEXT';
  }
  if (Array.isArray(node)) {
    // An array of nodes!
    return 'ARRAY';
  }
  if (typeof node.type === 'string') {
    // An element describing “host” (e.g. DOM) component: <div />
    return 'HOST';
  }
  if (typeof node.type === 'function') {
    // An element describing “composite” (user-defined) component: <Foo />
    return 'COMPOSITE';
  }
  throw new Error('Weird node: ' + node);
}

// To render a host element like <div />, we’ll generate
// its tag markup and render children inside.
// This is a simple implementation and doesn’t attempt to escape anything.
function renderHostElementToString(el) {
  // Separate children from attributes
  const { children, ...otherProps } = el.props;

  // Create an attribute string for markup
  let attributes = Object.keys(el.props)
    .map(propName => propName + '=' + el.props[propName])
    .join(' ');
  
  // If attributes exist, prepend a space to separate from tag
  if (attributes) {
    attributes = ' ' + attributes;
  }
  
  // Create tag strings for markup
  // For host elements, type is the tag name
  const openingTag = '<' + el.type + attributes + '>';
  const closingTag ='</' + el.type + '>';
  
  return (
    openingTag +
    // Render children recursively!
    renderToString(children) +
    closingTag
  );
}

// To render a composite component like <Foo />,
// we’ll call its type (`Foo`) with its props.
// We will then recursively render it.
function renderCompositeElementToString(el) {
  const renderedEl = el.type(el.props);
  return renderToString(renderedEl);
}

// Handle different types differently.
function renderToString(node) {
  var kind = getNodeKind(node);
  switch (kind) {
    case 'EMPTY':
      return '';
    case 'TEXT':
      return node.toString();
    case 'ARRAY':
      // Render each of them
      return node.map(renderToString).join('');
    case 'HOST':
      // <div />
      return renderHostElementToString(node);
    case 'COMPOSITE':
      // <Foo />
      return renderCompositeElementToString(node);
  }
}

// Let’s give it a try!

function Badge({ children }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <hr />
      {children}
      <hr />
    </div>
  );
}

function UserInfo({ name, location }) {
  return (
    <Badge>
      {name} lives in {location}.
    </Badge>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>
        Hello, React!
      </h1>
      <UserInfo
        name="Dan"
        location="London"
      />
    </div>
  );
}

document.body.innerHTML = renderToString(<App />);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create a function like this:

```
function MyComponent() {
  return null;
}
```

It is a normal JavaScript function, isn't it? But it can be turned into a React component. If you use [react-preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-react/) that allows you to use JSX syntax you can turn this function into a component that renders null:

```
<Welcome />
```

will produce:

```
React.createElement(MyComponent, null);
```

So a functional component is a component that was created from a function not by extending the React base class (`React.Component`).

It's just two ways to define them. You can play around and see what's behind the scenes with the [Babel online transpiler](https://babeljs.io/repl/).

Comment: Refer this link https://medium.com/@tejassavaliya/functional-components-vs-class-components-in-react-507db6a47439

Answer (score 0):

A functional component in React:

- Used for presenting static data
- Can't handle fetching data
- Easy to write

Example:

```
const Header = () => {
  return <Text>Hello World!</Text>
}
```